# Why do I get /bin/sh: aws: command not found in local-exec provisioner?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

I want to perform a lambda invocation from terraform when destroy is running.
The terraform job is run by Jenkins on remote server.

According to [this](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html) documentation I defined the following provisioner:

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
   when = destroy
   command = "aws lambda invoke --function-name ${var.lambda_name} --payload '{ \"someProperty\": \"someValue\" }' response.json"
}
```

the command syntax of lambda invoke is according to [AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/invoke.html)

But, when running Terraform getting the following error:

```
Error running command 'aws lambda invoke --function-name my-lambda-name --payload '{ "someProperty": "someValue" }' response.json': exit status 127. Output: /bin/sh: aws: command not found
```

Why do I get /bin/sh: aws: command not found in local-exec provisioner?

Answer (score 0):

local-exec is running on your local machine instead of the resource. So I would guess you are missing the aws-cli on your machine.

The command `which aws` will show whether or not you have aws-cli installed and available within your `PATH`? If it is not installed, follow the installation instructions for your OS.

Comment: I've edited the question, so in my case, the terraform job runs on remote machine hadled by Jenkins. And there is a aws-cli that is already installed there.